# Circle or point when plot cross candle

Tags: pine-script

Simple code for EMA but i want to add a circle when the EMA line cross a candle.

```
study(title="EMA 150", overlay=true)

longer = ema(close, 150)

plot(longer, color = aqua)
```

I can do for 2 plot or line but when it's just one, i have no find solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ta.crossover` and `ta.crossunder` functions to see if there is a cross.

Here is a `v5` example for you:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="EMA 150", overlay=true)
longer = ta.ema(close, 150)
plot(longer, color = color.aqua)

is_cross = ta.crossover(longer, low) or ta.crossunder(longer, high)
plotshape(is_cross ? longer : na, "Circle", shape.circle, location.absolute, color.aqua)
```